# Как поставить таймер?

Tags: javascript

Как поставить таймер? например `.empty();` бывает автоматический через 5 секунд

```
$(function(){$('.result').on('click', function (){$('.result').empty();});});
```

**Обновление**

Можно посмотреть здесь: http://rutube.ru/video/private/49b9e15f906d8f18f31ecef29cf95843/?p=TkcmJPxLIFryHXo-sPuLwA

Comment: `on('click', function () { setInterval(function() {$('.result').empty();}, 5000); `}); - дальше - clearInterval на повторный click и т.п.

Comment: @lgor, Спасибо но не работает посмотрите здесь https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/

Comment: что не работает? Я там не вижу ни setInterval, ни setTimeout.

Comment: @lgor, я поставил все равно не работает! https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/8/

Comment: @lgor, извините не знаю как можно объяснить. У меня сейчас закрывается только при клике! Как можно сделать чтобы автоматический закрывается через 5 секунд!?(без клик).

Comment: a-a-a: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/10/  или и то, и другое:  https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/11/

Comment: @Igor, Спасибо!!! мне нужно это http://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/11

Comment: "Первое заблуждение человечества: каждому кажется, что он говорит понятно."  Суворов В.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В нормальном JS есть функция `setTimeout(function, integer)` - выполнит функцию через указанное время.
В этоге как-то так:

```
$(function(){
    $('.result').on('click', function (){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.result').empty();
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо но не работает посмотрите здесь https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/

Comment: @TheDoctor Вы неверно интерпретируете понятие "очередь" (или "цепочка" в вашем случае) для функции `delay`. Этот метод не может являться полной заменой для `setTimeout`, ибо очередь в jQuery работает не с атомарными операциями, а с асинхронными. Метод `empty` -- атомарный. Он будет выполнен сразу по срабатыванию события `click`.

Comment: @KYRAN, Там даже `delay` нет, разумеется не сработает. 
Хотя он не сработал даже после вставки (я с jQuery не дружу), поэтому вот: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/1/

Comment: @VisioN, Благодарю за краткий экскурс.

Comment: @TheDoctor, извините не знаю как можно объяснить. У меня сейчас закрывается только при клике! Как можно сделать чтобы автоматический закрывается через 5 секунд!?(без клик).

Comment: @KYRAN, чувак, тогда нужно больше информации. Тут код вешает слушатель на клик и там действует таймер. Для того, чтобы закрывался без клика, нужен коллбэк в момент создания ".result".

Comment: @TheDoctor, Спасибо! извините брат решил http://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/11

Comment: "извините, брат, решил" - "извините, брат решил" - кто есть брат?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.result').on('click', function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('.result').empty();
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо но закрывается только (после клик) через 5 секунд

Comment: А вам нужно скрыть через 5 секунд после показа? По вашему коду не очень очевидно

Comment: извините не знаю как можно объяснить. У меня сейчас закрывается только при клике! Как можно сделать чтобы автоматический закрывается через 5 секунд!?(без клик).

Comment: Спасибо! извините брат решил http://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/11

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.result').on('click', 
        setTimeout(
            function(){ $('.result').empty(); }, 
            5000
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: извините не знаю как можно объяснить. У меня сейчас закрывается только при клике! Как можно сделать чтобы автоматический закрывается через 5 секунд!?(без клик).

Comment: Спасибо! извините брат решил http://jsfiddle.net/t3wfqffx/11